# Is there any way to send an email from Apex to Email-To-Case, with dynamic from address instead of Running User

Tags: email, apex-email-service, email2case, singleemailmessage

I have a form, where the user will fill all the information. Once the record gets created I wanted to invoke the Email-To-Case by passing record Id as the subject. Here, I wanted to set the From address of the user, during the SingleEmailMessage sending. But there is no method available other than "Organization-Wide Email Addresses", which is a static one. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Are you in Lightning or Classic?

Comment: Lightning Experience

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into this for a client which had an existing customization that worked in Classic, but not in Lightning to allow the `EmailMessage.FromName` field to be populated with the `User.Name` when an `OrgWideEmailAddress` is used. Lightning doesn't seem to support this (confirmed by Salesforce Tech Support).

I was looking at implementing a custom component that would execute on Save, but the business unit didn't want to pay the cost of developing it (an action alone wouldn't suffice). The company's agents are configured to use their `User.Name` and an `OrgWideEmailAddress` for various service departments entered in their org but Lightning doesn't respect these personal email settings.

Having an Action that calls a Lightning Component to execute on SUBMIT of the email is the only way I know of to do this. I don't think you'd want to run a Before Insert trigger on EmailMessage to do this if you're using enhanced email throughout your org.